# Как задать прозрачный фон в SurfaceView? Android

Tags: java, android, ui

В приложении имеется view с графиком, поверх которой располагается другая view, потомок SurfaceView. На SurfaceView предполагается возможность рисования различных объектов так, чтобы они находились поверх графика.

В данный момент в конструкторе SurfaceView вызываются методы:

```
setZOrderOnTop(true);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что с использованием метода setZOrderOnTop любой нарисованный объект начинает рисоваться поверх всего (например нарисованная фигура будет отображается не только поверх графика, но и поверх боковой менюшки, если её вызвать). Если не использовать setZOrderOnTop или вместо него прописать setZOrderMediaOverlay, то данной проблемы не возникнет, однако SurfaceView вместо прозрачного фона будет иметь однотонно чёрный.

Comment: Может как-то выключать `zOrderOnTop` при определенных событиях?

Comment: @Flippy фишка в том, что боковое меню не обязательно скрывает рисунок полностью. Ничто не мешает скрывать нарисованную фигуру, как только активируется меню, но это будет не совсем красиво и возможно кто-то подскажет более правильный способ решения проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, из-за специфики SurfaceView всё же не удастся сделать прозрачный фон, без размещения вьюшки поверх всего окна. Остаётся просто скрывать её при вызове менюшки :)